# Image push docker Registry Fails

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-image

I am trying to push an image to a private docker registry hosted on Linux Centos VM. I get an error :[image: dockerpusherror]

When I look for this error I get that its because of insecure registry, when I add this manually I get below error:[image: dockerinsecureregistrymanual]

I also try adding daemon.json file under /etc/docker and if I now restart docker service I get error attached.[image: Dockerrestarterror]

My docker info.[image: Dockerinfo]

Kindly help here!

[image: daemon.json]

Comment: Post your daemon.json too

Comment: `--insecure-registry` is a flag of the docker daemon, it's not for the docker command. Your `docker info` looks fine. Have your tried to push again?

Comment: I have added my daemon.json with the question. Still the error persists no success with Push.